# Reading data after insert into table using kafka

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I have a springboot application that performs an insert into a table(mysql). This in turn triggers and inserts into another table. Is it possible to read data from the table using kafka.

Comment: Have you heard of Kafka Connect or Debezium?

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in getting data from a database into Kafka, have a look at https://www.confluent.io/blog/no-more-silos-how-to-integrate-your-databases-with-apache-kafka-and-cdc

*Disclaimer: I work for Confluent, and wrote this blog post.*